# Single node parallelism with PL/Proxy?

Tags: postgresql

I have seen some suggest that single node parallelism is possible, but all of the material I have found so far deals with parallelizing across nodes. I am interested in getting large static queries to exercise multiple cores when a query maximizes on a single thread.

In a DWH environment, I would like to use PL/Proxy to do the following:

- develop functions that query a local database on a single node
- individually querying partitions
- aggregating the intermediate data sets into a single result

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't give full anser now, but the key to success is (a) use of authorization schemas and (b) 'user=' option in plproxy.get_cluster_partitions config function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible: check this blogpost http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/12/02/the-secret-ingredient-in-the-webscale-sauce/